# Jquery - open link in new tab with .fadeOut

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, tabs, new-operator

I have a problem with some effects in Jquery. I used a tutorial of the Iphone slider and everything was fine except that it should not load the final page in a new tab after "unlocked". Default it is the same page.

code:

`$("#iphone-inside").fadeOut("slow", function(){
               window.location="index.html";

        });`

Since I am pretty new to jquery, i did some trial and error but...

the new tab i get with window.open=('myURL') but it will just work with .click event. that way the slider is kind of useless. I tried the .fadeTo but some how it opens a pop-up and not a new tab.

Answer (score 5):

JavaScript cannot open a new tab. Tab behavior is controlled by user configuration options only.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just asking how to control it on your computer, it depends on your browser. Each browser has its own settings for how to open new pages.

In IE7+, go to Tools -> Internet Options.  Click 'Settings' in the Tabs group near the bottom of the dialog. Here you will see several options for configuring default behavior.

In Firefox, its under Tools -> Options -> Tabs.  The first checkbox toggles the behavior.

In Chrome, you would have to install an extension from the gallery to make this happen. [This may help](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=4133b1f920886b52&hl=en).

In Safari, navigate to https://www.google.com/chrome and click "Download Google Chrome". Then click the little red circle at the top left.

This cannot be controlled pragmatically from your javascript code!